# VBA Open multiple files in selection order

Tags: vba

I want to make a list of files which I would select by mouse. To do that I used FileDialog. That's ok, but I can't see how can I get a list of the files in order I have picked them. They seem to be ordered exactly as displayed in the file dialog.

I have found [this](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/509803-cmdialog-file-open-multiple-file-selection-order) topic on Bytes.com but my problem has remained unsolved. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You'd have to create your own userform and pick up the selection while it is happening - that way you'd have the order of selection.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a resource online how to achieve that? Is standard Microsotf VBA reference enough? I can use built-in features of VBA like buttons, listboxes and so on, but I expect that creating such a dialog would involve some 'lower level' interaction. What I have particularly in mind is access to file system structure/developing some system-related behaviours and so on. Are there any other options do perform exactly the same task but involving Python/C++? In that case of course VBA is ruled out.

Answer (score -1):

Below code will Help you to select multi files using dialog box

```
Sub test1()

Dim fileToOpen As Variant
    Dim outputfolder As String
    Dim i As Long


fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(fileToOpen) Then

        For i = LBound(fileToOpen) To UBound(fileToOpen)

       ' Do your Coding here

        Next i
    Else
          MsgBox "No files were selected."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't answer the original question, which was returning not only the selected files, but also the **order** in which they were selected. Getopenfilename can't do that.